# What could be causing this Xcode error and what are potential solutions? "Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report..."

Tags: swift, swiftui

**Problem:**

I am receiving the following error in my `ContentView` struct, specifically on the `var body: some View {` line.

**Error:**

> Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs)

**My Code:**

```
//  ContentView.swift

import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Map(coordinateRegion: viewModel.$mapRegion, annotationItems: viewModel.locations) { location in
                MapAnnotation(coordinate: location.coordinate) {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "star.circle")
                            .resizable()
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                            .background(.white)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                        
                        Text(location.name)
                            .fixedSize()
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        viewModel.selectedPlace = location
                    }
                }
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            Circle()
                .fill(.blue)
                .opacity(0.3)
                .frame(width:32, height: 32)
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        let newLocation = Location(id: UUID(), name: "New Location", description: "", latitude: viewModel.mapRegion.center.latitude, longitude: viewModel.mapRegion.center.longitude)
                        viewModel.locations.append(newLocation)
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                    .padding(20)
                    .background(.black.opacity(0.75))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .padding(.trailing)
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: viewModel.$selectedPlace) { place in
            Text(place.name)
            EditView(location: place) { newLocation in
                if let index = viewModel.locations.firstIndex(of: place) {
                    viewModel.locations[index] = newLocation
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

```
//  ContentView-ViewModel.swift

import Foundation
import MapKit

extension ContentView {
    @MainActor class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50, longitude: 0), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 25, longitudeDelta: 25))
        @Published var locations = [Location]()
        @Published var selectedPlace: Location?
    }
}
```

```
//  Location.swift

import Foundation
import CoreLocation

struct Location: Identifiable, Codable, Equatable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var description: String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }
    
    static let exampleLocation = Location(id: UUID(), name: "Test Palace", description: "Where Test lives with his Test", latitude: 51.501, longitude: -0.141)
 
    //since ID is unique, this lets you compare just ID. You can do == because struct conform to identifiable
    static func ==(lhs: Location, rhs: Location) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

The error occurred after I moved the following 3 properties (`var mapRegion`, `var locations`, `var selectedPlace`) out of the `ContentView` struct (where they were `@State` variables) and made them `@Published` variables. Before this, my code compiled successfully. I am trying to structure my project with MVVM, and expected reorganizing my code to not interfere with when I compiled.

However, when I moved these into a new file called "ContentView-ViewModel.swift" and made them `@Published` variables, and also initialized a new variable in `ContentView`, `viewModel = ViewModel()` and prefixed `viewModel.` in the appropriate locations, I receive the aforementioned error in my `ContentView` struct.

I also tried cleaning the project. I wasn't able to solve the issue with ChatGPT, looking through forums or Stackoverflow, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is usually a typo, comment out sections of code until you find it

Comment: Thanks! I found the source of the problem. I was placing the $ bindings in the wrong place.

Comment: Anytime, you can post it as an answer and mark it as a solution so other can benefit.